# I can not end a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to use Thread.Abort() but it's freezing my GUI .... It freezes all the elements except the statusLabel ... it keeps updating ... whats the problem with the code...

I do not know why this is happening, I thought it might be the try catch block, but it is in the thread ... I believe it does not interfere with anything

Code:

https://paste.lamlam.io/davagokeza.cs#o34Oy3vsWwK95ya0B5bk2leI8R6xweyk

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RunAsWebServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebServer ws;

        List<Proxy> resultList;

        bool continueTask = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

            CreatServer("127.0.0.1:8080");
        }



        public void CreatServer(string server)
        {
            ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://"+ server +"/");
            ws.Run();
        }


        public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            var query = request.QueryString;
            var ip =  query["ip"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {
                return "It's working...";
            }
            return new Whoer().Check(ip);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            ws.Stop();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ws.Stop();
                CreatServer(textBox1.Text.Trim() + ":"+textBox2.Text.Trim());

                MessageBox.Show("Server: " + textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + " OK!", "Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Server: " + textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text + " Failed!", "Server", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        List<Thread> threads;
        ConcurrentQueue<string> queue;

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (threads != null)
            {
                foreach (var t in threads)
                {
                    if (t != null)
                    {
                        if (t.IsAlive)
                        {
                            t.Abort();
                            //MessageBox.Show("Wait all threads finish" + " " +t.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                            //return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            continueTask = true;

            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Starting...";

            queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(File.ReadAllLines(textBox3.Text));

            threads = new List<Thread>();

            resultList = new List<Proxy>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => {

                    while (continueTask)
                    {

                        if (queue.Count == 0)
                        {
                            continueTask = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        var proxy = "";
                        queue.TryDequeue(out proxy);
                        if (proxy != string.Empty)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Proxy result = new Whoer().Check2(proxy);

                                resultList.Add(result);

                                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = result.Ip + "|" + result.Status;
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                //
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

                thread.Start();
                threads.Add(thread);
            }

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in resultList)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (item.Status.ToLower() == "live")
                    {
                        if (checkBox1.Checked)
                        {
                            if (item.IsBlackListed == "Yes" || item.IsProxy == "YES")
                                return;
                        }

                        results.Add(item.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllLines("results.txt", results.ToArray());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var open = new OpenFileDialog()
            {
                ValidateNames = true,
                Filter = "Text|*.txt"
            };

            if(open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox3.Text = open.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (threads != null)
            {
                foreach (var t in threads)
                {
                    if (t != null)
                    {
                        if (t.IsAlive)
                        {
                            t.Abort();
                            //MessageBox.Show("Wait all threads finish" + " " +t.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                            //return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            //if (threads != null)
            //{
            //    continueTask = false;

            //    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Waiting...";
            //}
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                mynotifyicon.Visible = true;
                mynotifyicon.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            }
        }

        private void mynotifyicon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            mynotifyicon.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aborting the wrong thread? you could be ending the GUI thread

Comment: There is no `Thread.Abort()` in shared code.

Comment: @Sham  look at button5_Click event

Comment: Use `Task` instead of `Thread` if using .net framework 4.0 or later.

Comment: _"The problem with Thread.Abort is that it can interrupt the progress of the target thread at any point. It does so by raising an 'asynchronous' exception, **an exception that could emerge at more or less any point in your program.**"_ [How To Stop a Thread in .NET (and Why Thread.Abort is Evil))](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation)

Comment: Why `Thread`, not standard `Task` with `TaskCancellationSource` and `CancellationToken`?

Comment: Don't *ever* set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`  All that's doing is saying you don't want your program to work.  There is never a valid use case for doing that.  You've just learned one of many reasons why.